# f# - looping through array

Tags: f#

I have decided to take up f# as my functional language.

My problem: Give a bunch of 50digits in a file, get the first 10 digits of the sum of each line. (euler problem for those who know)

for example (simplified):
1234567890

The sum is 45
The first "ten" digits or in our case the "first" digit is 4.

Heres my problem, 
I read my file of numbers, 
I can split it using "\n" and now i have each line, and then I try to convert it to an char array, but the problem comes here. I can't access each element of that array.

```
let total =
    lines.Split([|'\n'|])
    |> Seq.map  (fun line -> line.ToCharArray())
    |> Seq.take 1
    |> Seq.to_list  
    |> Seq.length
```

I get each line, convert it to array, i take the first array (for testing only), and i try to convert it to list, and then get the length of the list. But this length is the length of how many arrays i have (ie, 1). It should be 50 as thats how many elements there are in the array.

Does anyone know how to pipeline it to access each char?

Comment: Its not very clear what you're asking for. Could you rephrase your question in the form of "here's my input [ . . . ], here's my desired output [ . . . ]"

Comment: Neat how you sumBy bigint.Parse!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My final answer:

```
let total =
    lines.Split([|'\n'|])
    |> Seq.map (fun line -> line.ToCharArray() |> Array.to_seq)      
    |> Seq.map (fun eachSeq -> eachSeq 
                               |> Seq.take 50 //get rid of the \r
                               |> Seq.map (fun c -> Double.Parse(c.ToString()))
                               |> Seq.skip 10
                               |> Seq.sum                                
                               )
    |> Seq.average
```

is what i got finally and it's working :).

Bascially after I convert it to charArray, i make it a sequence. So now i have a sequence of sequence. Then I can loop through each seqquence.

Comment: You shouldn't need Array.to_seq - Seq.length works for arrays as well.

Comment: A char array is already a sequence. What you've written is equivalent to lines.Split([|'\n'|]) |> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Length)

Comment: Your way is okay now, but I don't need the length. I needed to work with the string thats pure digits and convert it to integers.

Comment: Also note that you could merge those two top-level Seq.maps if you wanted to.

Comment: You could use a String as Delimiter for string.Split to get rid of the "\r" too.
lines.Split([|"\r\n"|], System.StringSplitOptions.None)

Answer (score 5):

`Seq.take` is still returning a `seq<char array>`. To get only the first array you could use `Seq.nth 0`.

Comment: I know, i've posted a new answer. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for, but I believe you're trying to write something like this:

```
lines.Split([|'\n'|) |> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Length)
```

This converts each line to a sequence of integers representing the length of each line.

Comment: 00000000
11111111
22222222

It will take each line and get the length of that line which is not what I am looking for. I was looking to convert "00000000" to '0', '0', '0' and so on, and then to 000000000 (int). 

i've posted my answer now I have figured it out.thanks :)

Comment: I know what you mean now, but it didnt work. If you try it you'll know what i mean (or maybe I explained the question wrong)

Comment: Your way is okay now, but I don't need the length. I needed to work with the string thats pure digits and convert it to integers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

```
string(Seq.sumBy bigint.Parse (data.Split[|'\n'|])).Substring(0, 10)
```

Comment: Neat how you sumBy bigint.Parse!

Answer (score 1):

I copied the data into a string, each line separated by x. Then the answer is one line (wrapped for SO):

```
let ans13 = data |> String.split ['x'] |> Seq.map Math.BigInt.Parse 
                                                      |> Seq.reduce (+)
```

If you are reading it from a file, you'd add the file reading code:

```
let ans13 = IO.File.ReadAllLines("filename") |> Seq.map Math.BigInt.Parse
                                                            |> Seq.reduce (+)
```

Edit: Actually, I'm not sure we're talking about the same Euler problem -- this is for 13, but your description sounds slightly different. To get the first 10 digits after the summing, do:

```
printfn "%s" <| String.sub (string ans13) 0 10
```